# Should you create an unlimited number of threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

The program I am writing asks the user for an unlimited number of items and my program will do something with each of those items. I made my program do this over 3 threads, so it will finish faster. With the program I have now it continues to loop through checking if each thread is still running then if 1 of the 3 isn't running it creates a new one. The only reason I create a new one is that it says a thread can only be used once. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should use a thread pool.

Comment: @SLaks I seen that earlier today, but couldn't find a good explanation or example of how it works. I don't like to use something if I don't know why it works. If you could add a great example of one that would be awesome :)

Comment: unlimited number of threads guarantees OutOfMemoryError, use a thread pool as @SLaks suggested

Comment: "If 1 of the 3 isn't running it creates a new one" - you could make it so 1 of the 3 doesn't stop running in the first place?

Comment: @immibis It finishes it's task or it encounters an error

Comment: @J.Doe You could make it so each thread does more than one task and doesn't stop when it encounters an error.

Comment: @immibis Could 3 threads access the same hashtable from another class and edit/change it's data and the change be made on an global scale?

Comment: @J.Doe "Could 3 threads access the same hashtable" - let me stop you right there, *NO*. Unless you like random unpredictable errors and maybe corrupted data. (Actually, having 3 threads reading from the same hashtable would be okay, but you said you wanted to change it)

Comment: @immibis I guess the threads doing more than 1 task won't work unless I change the entire program. the main thread loops through user entering the objects, while the other 3 complete a task with each object that the main thread is adding to the hash table.

Comment: @immibis All the threads would be changing is a boolean in the hashtable stating whether it's object has been used or not

Answer (score 1):

No you shouldn't you should use a ThreadPool, luckily Java already has all you need under the package : `java.util.concurrent`

Example using a Thread pool with 10 concurrent threads :

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        exec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            exec.submit(new MyTask(System.out));
        }
        exec.shutdown();
    }

    public static class MyTask implements Runnable {
        PrintStream out;
        public MyTask(final PrintStream out) {
            this.out = out;
        }
        public void run() {
            out.println("MyTask executed in : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Look at `java.util.concurrent.Executors` class to find other thread pools implementation (scheduled pool, mono thread pool....), also your task could implement the interface `Callable`, which gives you more control for exception catch and a return object from your thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of Java concurrency thread pools from `Executors` factory class and set the number of processors which can be obtained from `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();` as a thread pool size for maximum performance.